# An error when running an example

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to use the `numpy.fft.fft`.

When I run the example in the bottom of this page ([numpy.fft.fft](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html#numpy.fft.fft)), there is an error and the figure is weird.

How to make it right?  I guess the error is related with `backend_macosx.py`?

The following are all of the code:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import numpy as np
>>> t = np.arange(256)
>>> sp = np.fft.fft(np.sin(t))
>>> freq = np.fft.fftfreq(t.shape[-1])
>>> plt.plot(freq, sp.real, freq, sp.imag)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x1046c8c50>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x1046c8ed0>]
>>> plt.show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xujc/.Software/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xujc/.Software/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1034, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/Users/xujc/.Software/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xujc/.Software/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2086, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/xujc/.Software/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xujc/.Software/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1093, in draw
    renderer)
  File "/Users/xujc/.Software/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1042, in _get_tick_bboxes
    extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
  File "/Users/xujc/.Software/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 754, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
  File "/Users/xujc/.Software/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 320, in _get_layout
    ismath=False)
  File "/Users/xujc/.Software/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 158, in get_text_width_height_descent
    width, height, descent = self.gc.get_text_width_height_descent(unicode(s), family, size, weight, style)
TypeError: must be string, not int
```

[image: figure]

ps:

```
$python
Python 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (x86_64)| (default, Jun  2 2014, 12:48:16)
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
```

`matplotlib` version is `1.3.1`.

Comment: It is ok if I just save the figure (`plt.savefig('a.eps')`) without show it.

Answer (score 1):

Work fine for me, if you click the small ">>>" you will get something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
t = np.arange(256)
sp = np.fft.fft(np.sin(t))
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(t.shape[-1])
plt.plot(freq, sp.real, freq, sp.imag)

plt.show()
```

python version

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jul  9 2014, 20:49:24) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

matplotlib..

```
matplotlib (1.3.1)
```

So try going back to use the mac distribution of python, since changing this it creates more problems that what it could solve.

I install all libraries with pip. :)

Result::
[image]

Comment: Thank you for trying the example. If I can't solve it, I will try to go back to use the mac distribution of python. After all, it is kind of laborious to install all of the libraries one by one. :)  Besides, the [Python 2.7.7 Release](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.7/) says 'includes numerous bugfixes over 2.7.6', therefore I don't tend to use version `2.7.6`. BTW, are you using 'OSX Yosemite'?

Comment: @leftriver yes i am, is almost the same in this matters, I know is can be laborious to install all libraries, but pip or brew make it a lot easier.

Comment: I use python 2.7.8 and other libraries installed by `brew` and `pip`, and I still get this error. Actually, I always get this error when I try to show the figure with `plt.show()`.

Comment: I guess this is a bug, and I asked another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995878/always-get-this-error-when-show-the-figure-typeerror-must-be-string-not-int) .